# Easy way to check if multi-dimensional arrays are empty in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I can't go into a for next loop if there is nothing in the array. 
To check if a single dimension array is empty I use:

```
If Len(Join(arr,"")) > 0 then
```

But that strategy does not work with multi-dimensional arrays.  Sometimes I uses *Booleans* but I have a feeling that there must be a simpler way to check if a multi-dimensional array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `VarType` function which [checks the type of a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function).

Example of checking that an array is empty:

```
If VarType(arr) = vbEmpty Then
    ' do something
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the variant (not the datatype :)) of VBA you're using doesn't have some sort of standard library function to check metadata of an array, why not just add a extra dimension with the empty or filled status of the array and just check that?